# unable to connect to mysql server using flask and pyodbc

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I use the below code for connecting to MYSQL DATABASE using flask and pyodbc package. AS I try to run a flask project.

**app.py**

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_cors import CORS
from api import create_app, init_db
from api.common.models.models import db
import os


load_dotenv()
app_name = os.environ.get('FLASK_APP') or ''
app = create_app()

# security
cors_allowed_origins = os.environ.get('CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS', [])
CORS(app) # , origins=cors_allowed_origins

# sqlalchemy
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "mssql+pyodbc://USERNAME:PASSWORD@./DBNAME?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server"
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = FALSE
db = init_db(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    str = 'Hello World {0}'.format(app_name)
    return str

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run()
```

I get the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pyodbc.OperationalError) ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with the connection string, you are trying to connect to MySql but the connection string is to connect to MSSQL:

```
"mssql+pyodbc://USERNAME:PASSWORD@./DBNAME?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server"
```

But for MYSQL is one of the following:

```
# default
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://scott:tiger@localhost/foo'

# mysqlclient (a maintained fork of MySQL-Python)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+mysqldb://scott:tiger@localhost/foo'

# PyMySQL
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://scott:tiger@localhost/foo'
```

Check the official documentation:

[Database Urls](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html#database-urls)